# Best way to add null value to IEnumerable as First Record with an example

Tags: c#, linq

The following code returns the `List` as Key-Value Pair what is available in the Database using Dapper. The KeyValue Pair is being called from the WebApi Controller and being served as `Json`, so that list can be used by the Javascript script for a drop down box.

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> KeyValueList()
{
    const string sql = @"SELECT  Key ,
                        Value
                FROM    Constants";
    var result = DataStoreReader.Query(ConnectionHelper.GetConnectionString, sql)
        .Select(item =>
        new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.Key, item.Value));

    return result;
}
```

The above code returns the following result as Json.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "key": 1,
      "value": "Value - 1"
    },
    {
      "key": 2,
      "value": "Value - 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But, I need this result, notice the first object as `null` must be automatically added. However, my database doesn't have the null record and it is *not possible to add*.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "key": null,
      "value": "Select"
    },
    {
      "key": 1,
      "value": "Value - 1"
    },
    {
      "key": 2,
      "value": "Value - 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this because your key is of type `int`, it cannot have `null` value. In general, it sounds, returning `null` from a non-null database value sounds like a bad idea and leads to data objects and database types mismatch. Perhaps, it is better to review if you really need this or if you can do it in another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your key parameter type to **int?**, and:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> KeyValueList()
{
    const string sql = @"SELECT  Key ,
                        Value
                FROM    Constants";
    var result = DataStoreReader.Query(ConnectionHelper.GetConnectionString, sql)
                                .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<int?, string>(item.Key, item.Value))
                                .ToList();
    //Insert the first/default element
    result.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<int?, string>(null, "Select"));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have just posted my solution which is quite similar to yours, so I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: One suggestion: use LINQ `Aggregate` method overloads to supply an `new List { new KeyValuePair<int?, string>(null, selectValue) });` as
 a seed value. This should save you from inserting at the head of a list.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of you all, I managed to achieve it. Here is the solution I have got so far.

1. Converted the int to int? to accept null.
2. Converted the Dapper result to `.ToList()`.
3. Inserting the object row manually to the `List` with null and constant value.

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> KeyValueList()
{
    const string selectValue = "Select";
    const string sql = @"SELECT  Key ,
                        Value
                FROM    Constants";

    var result = DataStoreReader.Query(ConnectionHelper.GetConnectionString, sql)
        .Select(item =>
        new KeyValuePair<int?, string>(item.Key, item.Value)).ToList();

    result.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<int?, string>(null, selectValue));

    return result;
}
```